# How to make output text start on top left corner of console after newlines

Tags: c++, windows

After reading about why I should not use system("CLS"), I used `cout << string(100, '\n')` to clear the console screen. However, the new text would display at the last line of the console output. How can I fix that?

Using VC++ 2012.

Comment: Man, I forgot did something similar in C long time ago, after clearing display you are suppose to reset cursor position.

What OS are you using?

Comment: @CamelToe How? Can you provide a link or snippet?

Comment: @VladimirLemin you are using Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're apparently writing the code for Windows, you could use the Windows console functions, something like this:

```
#include <windows.h>

void ClrScrn(int attrib, char filler = ' ') {

    HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD pos = { 0, 0};
    DWORD written;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO screen_attr;
    unsigned size;

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(screen, &screen_attr);

    size = screen_attr.dwSize.X * screen_attr.dwSize.Y;

    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(screen, filler, size, pos, &written);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(screen, attrib, size, pos, &written);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, pos);
}
```

This lets (requires) you specify the color it'll be cleared to in the parameter `attrib`, so usage would be something like this:

```
ClrScrn(FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY | BACKGROUND_BLUE);
```

If you want to clear the screen to something other than blanks, you can specify a character to fill with as well. For example to fill the screen with dark red smiley faces on a blue background:

```
ClrScrn(FOREGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE, '\1');
```

Comment: Is there any way to make this universal? Also, if I just wanted to use this with the normal console background, what should I use in the function call?

Comment: "Universal"? You mean portable (e.g., able to work on Linux or MacOS)? If so, I'd probably handle it at the makefile level--that is, have a separate implementation for each target OS, and decide which to use at build-time. The "normal" console is light grey on black, which you'd get with: `ClrScrn(FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN);`.

Comment: Hm, is FillConsoleOutputCharacter(screen, ' ', size, pos, &written);     FillConsoleOutputAttribute(screen, 0, size, pos, &written); a working alternative without all the parameters?

Comment: @VladimirLenin: At the very least you also need the `SetConsoleCursorPosition` (that's what moves the cursor up to the top-left, the original topic of the question).